# Movie from the '90s about a girl who wishes for her life to be perfect and wakes up in a parallel world

Tags: story-identification, movie, parallel-universe

I remember growing up I watched a movie about a girl tired of being poor, her life and her boyfriend; she fantasized about a football star. One December 25th, she wished her life was perfect and she wakes up married to the famous football guy and is the boss at her job as a TV producer. In this world, they write backwards.

Answer (score 7):

Is this the 1998 TV movie, ***[Twice Upon a Time](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0177310/)***, starring Molly Ringwald...?

> A woman (Molly Ringwald), unhappy with her life, makes a wish for a different life which whisks her to a parallel world where her life is different and she falls back in love with her boy friend (George Newbern).

The main character, Beth, is about to turn 30 but is dissatisfied with her life.

She has a loving boyfriend, Joe, whom she knows secretly plans to propose to her, but they live in a modest house together, he drives a crappy car, and he hasn't found himself yet in the eyes of her best friend.

She works for a TV show called 'Stranger Than Fiction,' where she's applied for the position of on-air producer, but another female co-worker is given the job.

Also, her ex-boyfriend, Nick -- whom she dumped in high school -- is now a baseball star, and she learns from a news report on TV that he's recently gotten engaged to another woman.

She happens to watch a segment on the TV show she works for that discusses the possible existence of parallel universes where history might've unfolded a little differently.

After a romantic dinner with Joe, they break a wishbone together, and it's implied that she makes an unspoken wish. The next morning, she wakes up in an alternate reality where her life is very different.

In this world, she's married to Nick, who's still a baseball star. They live in a huge, glamourous house together and he drives a luxury car.

She goes to her workplace, where she learns that she's now the producer with her own office. The guy who was her boss in the other reality is now her personal assistant.

The TV show she works for is still reporting on the possible existence of parallel universes, and she realises that she must now be in an alternate reality with an alternate history.

The differences in this world extend beyond her own personal life. For example, some aspects of technology are a little different, and all text in this world is reversed on the horizontal axis.

You can watch the whole movie on YouTube. Beth wakes up in the alternate reality at around the 21:15 mark.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like *13 Going on 30*. From [IMDB](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0337563):

> After total humiliation at her thirteenth birthday party, Jenna Rink wants to just hide until she's thirty. Thanks to some wishing dust, Jenna's prayer has been answered. With a knockout body, a dream apartment, a fabulous wardrobe, an athlete boyfriend, a dream job, and superstar friends, this can't be a better life. Unfortunately, Jenna realizes that this is not what she wanted. The only one that she needs is her childhood best friend, Matt, a boy that she thought destroyed her party. But when she finds him, he's a grown up, and not the same person that she knew

Comment: Do people write backwards in the world the character woke up in? That was one of the details mentioned in the question.

Comment: Not as far as I remember