# Movie about a woman in an alternate universe who gets to have the life she thought she wanted, but she still isn't happy with it

Tags: story-identification, movie, parallel-universe

I saw this movie almost 20 years ago. There was a woman who thinks her life might be better if she were with someone else. She has a boyfriend or husband already, but she thinks she would be happy if she were with guy who is baseball player or something like that.

Then she gets to have the life she wanted, but she still isn't happy with it. She falls in love with her boyfriend again, but he has someone else in that alternate life.

Comment: This one? https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/272590/movie-from-the-90s-about-a-girl-who-wishes-for-her-life-to-be-perfect-and-wakes/274275#274275

Comment: @Jontia yes this is it :) thank you so much. Can't believe finally find it. I was searching for really long time. you sure are fast

Comment: @Jontia - Worth posting as an answer since we can't dupe it off.

Answer (score 13):

This is the Molly Ringwald 1998 movie [Twice Upon a Time](https://m.imdb.com/title/tt0177310/).

> A woman (Molly Ringwald) unhappy with her life makes a wish for a different life--that whisks her to a parallel world where her life is different and she falls back in love with her boyfriend (George Newbern).

A much more detailed answer is available [over here.](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/272590/movie-from-the-90s-about-a-girl-who-wishes-for-her-life-to-be-perfect-and-wakes/274275#274275)